A naive question regarding the Navier Stokes equation
Assume that a function satisfies the heat equation. Does it also satisy the NS equations when you define the pressure such that its gradient is equal to the negative of the nonlinear term and the force term is identically 0. Are such solutions acceptable?

Could you write down the statement in a more formal way?

No, because the pressure is determined up to a constant by the velocity. To see this, consider the incompressible Navier-Stokes equations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
u_t + u\cdot \nabla u &= -\nabla p + \mu \Delta u \\
\nabla\cdot u &= 0. 
\end{aligned}
$$
Now take the divergence of the first equation and use the fact that $\nabla\cdot(u_t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\nabla \cdot u) = 0$ to obtain
$$
-\Delta p = \nabla \cdot(u\cdot \nabla u - \mu \Delta u).
$$
The RHS can be simplified further, but it suffices to note that this is a Poisson equation that is typically posed with Neumann boundary conditions. For discussion of this, see this post. This means that the function $p$ is uniquely determined by $u$ up to an additive constant. This makes sense physically since only pressure gradients have an impact on incompressible fluid flow. In practice, we typically choose some surface or point in the domain or boundary and enforce $p=0$ there to obtain a unique solution to the pressure Poisson equation.
A natural question then is why do we include the pressure in the NS equations if it is defined essentialy uniquely from $u$. Why not just write everything in terms of the velocity? Here are a few answers to this question:

The relationship between pressure and velocity is nonlocal. Formally speaking, we have $p = -\Delta^{-1}(\nabla \cdot(u\cdot \nabla u - \mu \Delta u))$, where $\Delta^{-1}$ is the formal ivnerse of the Neumann Laplacian. The action of this operator can be given as a Green's function or some other integral operation and we find that $p(x)$ depends on values of $u$ away from $x$. This makes analysis and discretization of the equations quite difficult, as even approximating $u$ at one point now requires us to know its value at all other locations in the domain and we get densely coupled equations. The original pressure formulation is much cleaner to work with numerically since we can determine the values in the NSE only using values at specific points. We note that some mathematical analysis can become a bit easier by eliminating pressure by analyzing the resulting quadratic form, such as in Tao, 2016 Finite time blowup for an averaged three-dimensional Navier-Stokes equation.

While the Eulerian form of the Navier-Stokes quation do not admit a natural variational/Lagrangian characterization, we can interpret the pressure through a variational lens as the Lagrange multiplier corresponding to the constraint $\nabla\cdot u=0$. This is a bit of a loose analogy as Navier-Stokes does not extremize any known functionals, but this characterization can be made precise for the steady-state Stokes equation. This interpretation reflects the challenges mentioned in my first point where introducing a Lagrange multiplier allows us the freedom to not explicitly characterize inverse operators over the constraint set, but instead use an intermediate quantity that is the solution of a known equation.



In other word, we can start with the ansatz that the p is constant for the boundary but in that case we add another equation namely the laplacian of p is 0.

No. There is no ansatz for $p$. $p$ is uniquely determined up to a constant given a velocity field.
